# Detect an a Dictionary Object in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Does anyone know how to identify if an object passed to a function (classic asp/vbscript) is actually a dictionary object vs any other type?

Obviously I can do `isObject(myObj)` but that doesn't tell me if it's a dictionary collection or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can;

```
dim dict: set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
print typename(dict)

>>Dictionary
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize typename returned the type name of the object.